# Using runsettings file when running NUnit tests via command line

Tags: c#, command-line, nunit, runsettings

I created a runsettings file which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name ="environment" value="PROD" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

And then in my TestSetup portion (using LeanFT for UI tests) I specify that the target environment is contained under a paramater called environment

```
string env= TestContext.Parameters["environment"];
```

This doesnt seem to work, and I am not getting any particular error messages. Is this the right way to do this, or is there an easier way to just use Environment and something I pass into the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be more specific than "via the commandline" since there are a number of ways that folks run NUnit tests from the command-line.

If you are using the `nunit3-console.exe` runner, you pass run parameters to the framework using the `--params` option, for example:

`nunit3-console my.test.dll --params "environment=PROD"`

The `.runsettings` file is an artifact used by Visual Studio and recognized by the NUnit VS adapter, but not by NUnit itself.

You can use that from the command-line as well, using `vstest.console.exe`. If that's what you are using, you want the `/Settings` option in order to specify the file.

Two answers for the price of one! But if you are using **neither** `nunit-console` **nor** `vstest.console` you'll have to ask again. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am using the nunit console, using the command that essentially looks like [path\to\nunit-console] [dll].. If I specify --params "environment=PROD", what does the code look like to actually take that param and do something if there is no runsettings file that can be used for NUnit?

Comment: You access the value using `TestContext.Parameters` just as you described in your question. This is a framework feature. Each runner lets you set the parameter (assuming it supports it) in its own way. The original implementation was through a command-line option and the `.runsettings` file approach was added to hook it up to the adapter.

Comment: Thank you! This actually works great, very clean and easy to use. My only criticism on NUnit is the documentation. This is such a trivial issue, but i struggled to find examples (actual examples in code) from the NUnit documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Within a test could you use the following to write all your settings

```
   foreach (var name in TestContext.Parameters.Names)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Parameter: {0} = {1}", name, TestContext.Parameters.Get(name))
   }
```

Comment: I am not sure how this helps.. What I want is just to toggle this string env when I run the tests on the command line