# Use NUnit Prefilter by nunit3-console

Tags: nunit, data-driven-tests, nunit-console, autotest, testcasesource

I'm developing data driven tests using Nunit3 and .Net Core 3.1 and I have many tests with more different data sources, which sometimes have complex logic inside. When I want start only one tests I want to start only one data provider, but I run all. In 3.15.1 ver of NUnit framework was released PreFilter, which solve this problem.

But this feature available only on .runsettings file as I understood [docs](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html#prefilter).
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098041/using-runsettings-file-when-running-nunit-tests-via-command-line) question Charlie Poole says that .runsettings is only for VS adapter. But the VS adapter takes a long time to run my tests.

I found [info for configuration file](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Configuration-Files.html) but don't undestand what I can configure in this file 0_o

Can I run my tests by NUnit Console Runner 3.12.0-beta1 with PreFilter?

Comment: Incidentally, this is the type of configuration file the NUnit docs are referring to. These files are for configuring .NET Apps, rather than NUnit itself - so not what you're looking for here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid not, no.

There's an open issue to implement it here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/438. You'll see from the VS adapter docs there's several edge-case bugs around this, which will be more visible in the adapter than in the console. At this point in time, nobody has yet taken on that task of implementing this feature in the console.

Comment: If you have a single assembly to run, then you can use NUnitLite, which does implement prefilter. As Chris says, there are some edge cases you could run into but there are also workarounds for most of them.